# How to concatenate the result of columns to a new column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to concatenate the result of those columns to be the final result:

```
SELECT 
    ID, 
    CASE
        WHEN t1.SCORE <= 10 THEN '2A'
        WHEN (t1.SCORE > 20 AND t1.SCORE <= 30) THEN '2B'
        WHEN t1.SCORE > 30 THEN '2C'
    END AS Result1,
    CASE
        WHEN t2.POINT <= 10 THEN '2A'
        WHEN (t2.POINT > 20 AND t2.POINT <= 30) THEN '2B'
        WHEN t2.POINT > 30 THEN '2C'
    END AS Result2,

    -- CONCAT(Result1,Result2) AS FinalResult
FROM 
    Table1 t1 
INNER JOIN 
    Table2 t2 ON t2.CustomerID = t1.ID
```

How can I add an expression like this:

```
CONCAT(Result1, Result2) AS FinalResult
```

Comment: Do you mean you want 3 columns; Result1, Result2 and CONCAT(Result1,Result2) AS FinalResult.

Comment: @jarlh Yes buddy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap your query up as a *derived table*:

```
select Result1, Result2, CONCAT(Result1,Result2) AS FinalResult
from
(
    SELECT ID, 
            CASE
                WHEN t1.SCORE <= 10 THEN '2A'
                WHEN (t1.SCORE > 20 AND t1.SCORE <= 30) THEN '2B'
                WHEN t1.SCORE > 30 THEN '2C'
            END AS Result1,
    
            CASE
                WHEN t2.POINT <= 10 THEN '2A'
                WHEN (t2.POINT > 20 AND t2.POINT <= 30) THEN '2B'
                WHEN t2.POINT > 30 THEN '2C'
            END AS Result2

    FROM Table1 t1 INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.CustomerID = t1.ID
) dt
```

Comment: could you please explain to me what is dt ?

Comment: dt is just a name/alias. It can be used in the select, like `select dt.Result1, `. Some products require each derived table to be given such name.